# SQL to LINQ Group by convertion

Tags: sql, linq

I have an SQL statement and I want to convert it to LINQ.  The problem now is that I don't know how to group by it in LINQ.

Here is the code.

In SQL

```
select plp.ProspectsListID, p.Prospect_PII_Key 
from ProspectListProspect plp
join Prospects p
on p.ProspectsID = plp.ProspectsID
group by plp.ProspectsListID,p.Prospect_PII_Key
```

In LINQ

```
  var list1 = from plp in GetDataContext.SQLDataContext.GetTable<DataAccess.ProspectListProspect>()
                    join p in     GetDataContext.SQLDataContext.GetTable<DataAccess.Prospect>()
                        on plp.ProspectsID equals p.ProspectsID
                    select new
                    {
                        ProspectID = plp.ProspectsListID,
                        Prospect_PII_Key = p.Prospect_PII_Key
                    };
```

thanks

Jason

Answer (score 2):

tyr this

```
var list1 = from item in
                (
                   from plp in GetDataContext.SQLDataContext.GetTable<DataAccess.ProspectListProspect>()
                join p in     GetDataContext.SQLDataContext.GetTable<DataAccess.Prospect>()
                    on plp.ProspectsID equals p.ProspectsID
                  select new
                  {
                      ProspectID = plp.ProspectsListID,
                      Prospect_PII_Key = p.Prospect_PII_Key
                   }
                )
                group item by new {item.ProspectID ,item.Prospect_PII_Key } into grp
                select new
                {
                    ProspectID = grp.ProspectsListID,
                    Prospect_PII_Key = grp.Prospect_PII_Key
                }
```

;

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
var list1 = from plp in GetDataContext.SQLDataContext.GetTable<DataAccess.ProspectListProspect>()
                    join p in     GetDataContext.SQLDataContext.GetTable<DataAccess.Prospect>()
                        on plp.ProspectsID equals p.ProspectsID
             Group By Key = New With {plp.ProspectsListID,p.Prospect_PII_Key} Into Group                       
             Select Group;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list1 = from plp in GetDataContext.SQLDataContext.GetTable<DataAccess.ProspectListProspect>()
            join p in  GetDataContext.SQLDataContext.GetTable<DataAccess.Prospect>()
                   on plp.ProspectsID equals p.ProspectsID
            group p by new {plp.ProspectsListID,p.Prospect_PII_Key} into g
            select new
                {
                    ProspectID = g.Key.ProspectsListID,
                    Prospect_PII_Key = g.Key.Prospect_PII_Key
                };
```